# Joining laptop to Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory

I have personal laptop for home use only, but now I need to use my laptop at office.

In order  to use the laptop at the office I need to add my laptop to domain.

How do I do this?

Comment: Depends on the version of Windows on your laptop, and be aware that if it's a Home (or Home Premium if Vista or 7) you won't be able to join it to a Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly you can't personally add it, you need to be at least a Domain Admin to join a computer to a domain - contact your IT team.

Secondly your PC must be running a 'Pro' version of Windows (XP Pro, Vista or W7 Business/Enterprise/Premium).

Finally you might consider that you might not actually want your laptop joined to a domain it might add various restrictions to your computer - fine for a work computer but annoying for a personal PC.

As a footnote - I find it almost unthinkable to add a personal computer to a company domain - not your battle I know.

Comment: I'm guessing that somebody from the OP's IT team probably used the statement "Yeah, but it would have to be joined to the domain" as a statement as to why the OP's personal laptop would be unusable. I'd suspect the OP is looking for our help because, at the root of it, the IT team probably doesn't want his personal laptop being used on the network under any circumstances, and the "must be joined to the domain" statement was a convenient excuse.

Comment: @Evan - my thoughts exactly

Comment: Nitpicking I know, but non-Domain Admins actually can join computers if your policies/etc are set up to allow it.  We use a dedicated account for this task that has no other rights whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties dialogue for "my computer" (how you get to this varies between Windows versions, so you'll have to update your question with that info to get a more detailed instruction) there is a "network identification" tab which includes which workgroup or domain the computer considers itself to be in.

You can add the computer to the domain from here but you must have access to a user account on the domain with "domain administrator" privileges in order for it to succeed, if you do not have such an account you will have to ask your network admin(s). It should be noted that most corporate networks have a strict policy of not letting "random" machines (i.e. those not directly/completely controlled by their IT/infrastructure people) connect in this way.

Comment: thx so i will contact my IT admin and ask them to help me